# Is it possible to specify number of pages in rdcl report c#?

Tags: c#, .net, reportviewer, rdlc, page-numbering

I have a rdcl ready to be populated.
It *mainly* contains a table that occupies the whole width and a few Textboxes under it that show summary info.
Sometimes the table will have a lot of lines and other times only a couple of them. This makes the texboxes to end up in the same page or a 2nd (or a 3rd) depending on the situation.

I wanna know if it is possible to so specify a jump to the next page for the textboxes.
So for example even if the table has only 1 line, and there is enough space under it to fit the texboxes info in 1 page, i want them to start at the 2nd page. And if the table is too long and occupies 1 and a half pages, the textboxes should appear in the 3rd page, and so on.

I thought of creating a 2nd report with only the textboxes but then the page numbers do not match and also the reports are showed in different windows.

Any pointers are most welcome.

Comment: Tip: People are more likely to respond if you mark previous answers as accepted from your other questions. As it stands, you don't accept answers.

Comment: hi, related to that, I have one quesiton though, what to do if none of the answers given solved my problem? :S (this was for only one question)

Comment: It's a unique position to be put in, but I guess it can't be helped if true. I'd say if the answers helped you out at all, mark them as answers, but In your question put in an edit and mention what was helpful to you so future users can get the same bit of help you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, if the report objects exits on the same rdcl you can not send them to a certain page.

You can, however, alter the "PageBreak" option on the Table to "End". This will push everything after the table onto the next page.

This will help you get the desired results you are after.

**EDIT:**
You could also get rid of the numerous pages all together by changing the Report property "InteractiveSize" to a height of lets say 50in. This causes the report viewer to page break much less often (every 50 inches) and would most likely place all of your content on Page 1 in the report viewer.

Comment: Glad I could help, was trying to help you out for future questions as we've all been in a tricky spot at one time or another :). (It's also good practice to upvote the accepted answer as well so when people sort by votes in question it comes up on top.)